# How to temporarily switch PostgreSQL to logical replication to allow major version upgrade without downtime?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, high-availability, maintenance

We have a PostgreSQL cluster running on one master (`db1`) and two async hot-standby servers (`db2` and `db3`) replicating from it. All the servers are working as a backend for a web service and all the read/write transactions connect to `db1` and all read-only transactions are executed on hot-standby servers if possible. The clients are smart enough to fallback to talking to master if hot-standby servers are too delayed or down. All the servers have identical hardware so it doesn't matter which one is the master server.

We're planning to upgrade the PostgreSQL to newer major version and want to do that with minimal downtime.

We're currently using binary/physical streaming replication but that replication mode only supports running all servers on the same major version.

I know that logical streaming replication can be used to synchronize data between different major versios so to upgrade the whole system to more recent release, I've following idea:

- Start publishing changes on `db1` over logical replication: create a new logical replication slot called `db1_to_db3` for this purpose.
- Take `db3` down, upgrade the PostgreSQL to next major versio we want to use.
- Clear the whole database and manually copy the database schema from `db1` to `db3`.
- Configure `db3` as hot-standby and subscribe to slow `db1_to_db3`.
- Wait for `db3` to eventually synchronize.
- Then do the same thing for `db2` except make it synchronize from `db3`.
- Then promote `db3` as the new master. Only do it now that we have at least two servers (`db3` and `db2`) with the full database to avoid lots of downtime in case of server hardware failure.
- Finally upgrade the PostgreSQL to the next major version on `db1` and add it as a hot-standby replica for `db3`.

However, I have following open questions:

1. Does creating the logical replication slot on `db1` guarantee that `db3` can be syncronized from scratch?
2. Does publishing the logical slot increase WAL log disk usage? If so, how much (e.g. +100%?)
3. How to switch back from logical replication to binary replication in the future? I know that we don't want to use logical replication in long run because it doesn't handle DDL changes (schema changes).
4. Is it possible to lose transactions with logical replication? How to verify the databases actually have the same data?

In case it makes a difference, we're planning to upgrade from version 12.x to 14.x.

Comment: Alternative way to do this with very little downtime is to use `pg_upgrade --link`. However, that doesn't have recovery plan in case `pg_uprade` failed for any reason: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301517/29183

Comment: You cannot switch between physical and logical replication. You have to start from scratch each time.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe with "start from scratch" you mean that the initial sync cannot be accelerated but you have to rebuild the hot-standby from scratch when you switch between physical and logical replication, right? Publishing both physical and logical replication streams from master in parallel should be possible as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you can have both at the same time. Perhaps I didn't understand your complicated description, but I had the impression that you want to turn a streaming replication standby into a logical standby (which is possible), upgrade that way and turn the logical standby into a physical standby (which is not possible). Ignore my comment if I got you wrong.

Comment: Your comment answered my question 3. I have to convert standby servers one-by-one from logical replication to physical replication because I have to clear the database on the slave, then redo everything from `pg_basebackup`. That's okay but simply takes more time than I was hoping for.